# How to identify which app is locking up this hotkey? Ctrl+Shift+N

Tags: windows, shortcuts

I have over 100+ processes and have killed the obvious culprits by elimination, to see which app is locking up my key Combination.

Now I can't use this shortcut in Chrome for incognito, I also can't use it in Win Explorer for New Folder.

Can anyone share how to overcome this challenge please? Thanks!